# How to stop a statement in Python?

Tags: python

I am newly converting to Python and want to know how to stop or pause in a script for diagnostic purposes. For instance, I want to do something like:

```
If Condition_is_True:
     Statement
 else:
     print('Condition not met!')
     stop
```

I guess I can use the `try: except:` statement, but the condition won't raise an exception; or I can use a `while` statement, but it won't stop.

I knew I could also use the debugger (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), but I don't want to keep the debugger in the code permanently. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for a *Python debugger*?

Comment: No, not really. Using a python debugger is one way to do this, I guess. But I am wondering if there is a way to just stop the script and notify me that the condition is not met.

Comment: Use an IDE. Pycharm works like a charm

Comment: *"Using a python debugger is one way to do this"* - no, it is **the way** to do this. If you want to stop and inspect running code, you need a debugger (not necessarily `pdb`; the duplicate has several answers with other options). FWIW, +1 for @biobirdman's PyCharm recommendation.

Comment: `if ..: print('met'); exit()`...!?